# How to know the type of an interface key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

If I have for example this super simple interface:

```
interface Dog {
    name: string;
}
```

Is there any way to check the type of the key?
As for example, we do this easily with a normal var:

```
let hi: number = 2;

if(typeof hi === 'number') { // It's possible 
    console.log('yes, it is');
}


if(typeof Dog['name'] === 'string') { // It's not possible 
    console.log('yes, it is');
}
```

The error:  `'Dog' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Any suggestion?

Comment: types have no run-time. if you make an object that matches the interface ```let dog:Dog = { name: "foo" } ``` then ```typeof dog["name"]``` would work at runtime

Comment: As the error says, `Dog` is a type. To be equivalent, your first sample should be if (typeof number === 'number').

Comment: It's worth noting you can use `instanceof` to check whether an object was creating using a particular class/function like in the example in my answer below, fwiw

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in TypeScript are purely a compile time construct and don't persist at runtime. Thus you cannot do typechecks on that compile time construct.

The `typeof` operator in JavaScript does not have anything to do with the types you defined in TypeScript but does a runtime check. To use it that way (like with `typeof hi === 'number'`, you'd have to have an object of type dog:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
}

const x: Dog = { name: 'Duke' };

if (typeof x['name'] === 'string') {
  console.log('yes, it is');
}
```

This however would not bring much benefit in this particular case since TypeScript will already ensure that the name is a string so the condition will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

This requires runtime type meta-information which doesn't exist in TypeScript. TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript and JavaScript doesn't have metadata on types such as field type info in a class.

So my answer is, it is not possible to do what you are asking for directly.

All the sophisticated typing that you experience in TypeScript exists only during development.

Is it worth noting the with JavaScript you can do some basic checks on the type of something like this:

```
// some empty prototype function (can be a class)
function Plant() {
}

// use the function to create an object
let x = new Plant();

// checking the type of x returns 'object'
typeof x; // this returns 'object'

// you can also check whether x was created using `Plant`
x instanceof Plant; // this returns true
```